# How to disable Left Click of Mouse for a div using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using this code but it's not working.
Jquery Code: I am create div for captcha i want not copy or select this contents (Captcha code).

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#lo").on("contextmenu",function(e){
       return false;
    }); 
});
```

HTML Code:-

```
<div id="lo">CAPTCHACODE2321</div>
```

Comment: you mean right click?

Comment: i want disable left click

Comment: `$("#lo").on("click",function(e){
       return false;
    });` why do you want to restrict it?

Comment: Left doesn't do anything unless you `click` on any links or you have attached any `events` to any `elements`. Are you lefty? I mean Left hand is primary for you??

Comment: we can select any content with left click of mouse. so i want i want disable left click

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but that is just annoying and you can see the content in the source any way...

Answer (score 1):

You can try the below code

**HTML**

```
<div id="lo" class="preventLeftClick">wwww</div>
```

**Jquery**

```
$('.preventLeftClick').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
});
```

**Note:** You can use this with any number of `div`s. You just need to add the class `preventLeftClick` with that `div` only

Answer (score 0):

You can add a simple css3 rule in the body or in specific div, use `"pointer-events: none;"` property.

[Check this sample code](https://jsfiddle.net/2xz2s087/)

Answer (score 0):

try this its prevent the click it showing as normal mouse pointer when hover the hyper link .

```
<div id="lo" style="pointer-events:none;">wwww</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to disable [`pointer-events`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events) in css so no events would be generated.

```
#lo { pointer-events: none; }
```

> The element is never the target of mouse events; however, mouse events
>   may target its descendant elements if those descendants have
>   pointer-events set to some other value. In these circumstances, mouse
>   events will trigger event listeners on this parent element as
>   appropriate on their way to/from the descendant during the event
>   capture/bubble phases.

Another way would be to catch click and disable default browser behaviour.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#lo").on("click",function(e){
       e.preventDefault();
       return false;
    }); 
});
```